# How to write block definition using properties?

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks

I am writing a class for getting image from Photos Library.
I want one single method that will return selected image from library.
So i started writing a class named MediaBrowser.
I used block that will give selected image. But I am confused where to write block definition. Please correct the code if i am going wrong.

In MediaBrowser.h

```
@interface MediaBrowser : NSObject

typedef UIImage* (^MediaBrowserCompletionHandler)(void);

+ (id)sharedInstance;
- (BOOL)startMediaBrowserFromViewController:(UIViewController*)controller
                          completionHandler:(MediaBrowserCompletionHandler)completion;
@end
```

In MediaBrowser.m

```
@interface MediaBrowser () <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate>
@property (nonatomic, strong) MediaBrowserCompletionHandler completionHandler;
@end

@implementation MediaBrowser

static MediaBrowser *sharedMediaBrowser = nil;

+ (id)sharedInstance
{
    if (nil != sharedMediaBrowser) {
        return sharedMediaBrowser;
    }
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedMediaBrowser = [[MediaBrowser alloc] init];
    });
    return sharedMediaBrowser;
}

- (BOOL)startMediaBrowserFromViewController:(UIViewController *)controller completionHandler:(MediaBrowserCompletionHandler)completion
{
    self.completionHandler = [completion copy];
    if (([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum] == NO)
        || (controller == nil))
        return NO;

    UIImagePickerController *mediaUI = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    mediaUI.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;

    // Displays saved pictures from the Camera Roll album.
    mediaUI.mediaTypes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:(NSString *)kUTTypeImage, nil];

    // Hides the controls for moving & scaling pictures, or for
    // trimming movies. To instead show the controls, use YES.
    mediaUI.allowsEditing = NO;
    mediaUI.delegate = self;

    [controller presentModalViewController:mediaUI animated:YES];
    return YES;
}

// UIImagePickerControllerDelegate

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    NSString *mediaType = [info objectForKey: UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];
    UIImage *imageToUse;

    // Handle a still image picked from a photo album
    if (CFStringCompare ((CFStringRef) mediaType, kUTTypeImage, 0) == kCFCompareEqualTo) {
        imageToUse = (UIImage *) [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
        // Do something with imageToUse
        if (self.completionHandler) {
            // Pass here UIImage
            self.completionHandler();
        }
    }

    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

@end
```

Comment: I don't see a declaration of `self.completionHandler`?!?

Comment: @trojanfoe, In MediaBowser.m on line 2, i have declared completionHandler. Where should i write definition?

Comment: Ah yes.  Well you would implement it like any other property.

Answer (score 2):

I figured out the answer. I wanted to send selected image from `UIImagePickerController` to the calling class. I was writing wrong block. See corrected code below.

In MediaBrowser.h

block declaration shoudld be :

```
typedef void (^MediaBrowserCompletionHandler)(UIImage *selectedImage);
```

And in MediaBroser.m

Calling block should be :

```
if (self.completionHandler) {
     self.completionHandler(imageToUse);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
typedef UIImage* (^MediaBrowserCompletionHandler)(void);

@interface MediaBrowser : NSObject

@property (nonatomic,copy) MediaBrowserCompletionHandler handler;

@end
```

Comment: COPY is non ARC keyword. I am using ARC. So used STRONG.

Comment: @BH4451: copy is perfectly fine for ARC. And in fact Apple recommends using this attribute for block properties even with ARC [see Apple's guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithBlocks/WorkingwithBlocks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH8-SW12).

Answer (score 0):

This should be fine.

```
typedef UIImage* (^MediaBrowserCompletionHandler)(void);

@interface MediaBrowser : NSObject
....
@end
```